# How do I set http headers such that no caching occurs in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I have to set http headers in my ASP.NET Core MVC application such that the browser does not cache content. I take a look to
[How to clear browser cache in MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101354/how-to-clear-browser-cache-in-mvc-application) but it doesn't work on .NET Core platform.

I would like to do in .NET Core what was done in standard ASP.NET MVC in the post I linked to above.

Comment: @Cuppyzh I would like to do in .NET CORE what was done in standard MVC in the post I indicated.

Comment: If you do not want any caching then you can decorate your method or controller class with: `[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent browser caching (including Internet Explorer 11), you can decorate your method or controller class with:

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

You can read more about Response Caching in .NET CORE [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2).